# Cascading Delete / Update in LINQ-to-SQL class

Tags: sql, database, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am not deleting records permanently (just maintaining flag) but I'd like to know how cascading delete / update works in LINQ-to-SQL class.

**EDIT**

If I have similar situation e.g. maintaining **flag for Delete** option. How do you achieve **Cascading Delete for your database**?

Answer (score 2):

The database-level delete isn't a perfect solution, in this case DataContext knows nothing about the fact that objects are already deleted.
The better way is to handle the situation on the application level using association flags like [Association( ... DeleteRule = "cascade" ... )].

Answer (score 0):

u have 2 way ,which i know , for  it

1. a) u should define constraint in data layer (
   if  FK constraint exist  ur issue   delete on cascade or  update on cascade)
   b) write  stored procedure or function or trigger by using CTE  and  use  it in your app layer
2. take control in  app layer  and  write  your  function 
   But my advice is   make it  on data layer

Comment: According to your first option I should trigger a stored procedure using CTE but I have number of tables having F.K. (Foreign Key) of one table.

So how do I come to know that these many number of tables having F.K. from Master Table. In future If I add new table with F.k. or Drop one table with F.K. then I have to check out all the S.P. (Stored Procedure), & then I rewrite all logic. It is a big task. And let me know if I am thinking in wrong way.

Comment: If  u think  that it  takes many time,then you  write  your Stored Procedure Creator(it ll be  really  usefull  your other projects) or  use CodeSmith